# How would you structure these rest api endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

Let's say you have 4 types of data that are displayed similarly across 4 pages of a website like videos, articles, posts, etc.

Would you have individual routes to get the most recent 10 for each like `/type1/getall`, `/type2/getall`, etc...,

Or would you have one route like `getAllByType` that takes the type as a param and returns the respective data.

Thanks for your input

Comment: You should not use verbs in urls AMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd method of defining a common route getAllByType with a param is the most used and recommended format because that way your routes structure is clean and it also avoids Redundant code. Hope it helps.